# How can I scroll sprites when swiping using Cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, touch, parallax-scrolling

I'm adding 3 sprites (layers) to `CCParallaxNode`:

```
BGLayer = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Layer.png"];
[_backgroundNode
    addChild:BGLayer
    z:2
    parallaxRatio:layer1Speed   
    positionOffset:ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)
];
```

How can I create the scroll when swiping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! 
Add the `sprites` or `layers` to a `parralaxNode` object and `enable touch` on your `init method`, `Cocos2D` will do the magic for you.